# Bundler: Hey, where does this gem version suddenly come from?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bundle

I was told to use v0.6.5 of the rails-i18n gem, so I first checked whether I was already up to date, which I wasn't (v0.6.0). So I tried `gem update rails-i18n` (which doesn't seem to be the correct command to update a specific gem, but it seems to update all installed gems, right?), which didn't seem to update anything ("Nothing to update").

So I specified `gem 'rails-i18n', '>= 0.6.5'` in my Gemfile, and run `bundle`. This also didn't seem to install anything new (didn't take near a second to complete, and there are only "Using..." statements in the console output), but after another check, v0.6.5 was installed!

I'm a bit confused now, where did this version come from? Has it already been installed on my system? Then why didn't it show up when I first checked using `gem list | grep i18n`?

Take a look at my output to verify my statements.

```
macbuech:iq josh$ gem list | grep i18n
i18n (0.6.0)
rails-i18n (0.6.5)
macbuech:iq josh$ gem update rails-i18n
Updating installed gems
Nothing to update
macbuech:iq josh$ bundle
Using rake (0.9.2.2) 
Using i18n (0.6.0) 
Using multi_json (1.3.6) 
Using activesupport (3.2.1) 
Using builder (3.0.0) 
Using activemodel (3.2.1) 
Using erubis (2.7.0) 
Using journey (1.0.4) 
Using rack (1.4.1) 
Using rack-cache (1.2) 
Using rack-test (0.6.1) 
Using hike (1.2.1) 
Using tilt (1.3.3) 
Using sprockets (2.1.3) 
Using actionpack (3.2.1) 
Using mime-types (1.19) 
Using polyglot (0.3.3) 
Using treetop (1.4.10) 
Using mail (2.4.4) 
Using actionmailer (3.2.1) 
Using arel (3.0.2) 
Using tzinfo (0.3.33) 
Using activerecord (3.2.1) 
Using activeresource (3.2.1) 
Using addressable (2.2.8) 
Using ancestry (1.3.0) 
Using bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1) 
Using bson (1.5.2) 
Using bson_ext (1.5.2) 
Using bundler (1.1.4) 
Using highline (1.6.12) 
Using net-ssh (2.5.2) 
Using net-scp (1.0.4) 
Using net-sftp (2.0.5) 
Using net-ssh-gateway (1.1.0) 
Using capistrano (2.12.0) 
Using nokogiri (1.5.5) 
Using ffi (1.0.11) 
Using childprocess (0.3.2) 
Using libwebsocket (0.1.3) 
Using rubyzip (0.9.9) 
Using selenium-webdriver (2.24.0) 
Using xpath (0.1.4) 
Using capybara (1.1.2) 
Using capybara-firebug (1.1.0) 
Using json (1.7.3) 
Using capybara-webkit (0.12.1) 
Using carrierwave (0.6.2) 
Using mongo (1.5.2) 
Using mongoid (2.4.11) 
Using carrierwave-mongoid (0.2.1) 
Using chronic (0.6.7) 
Using chunky_png (1.2.5) 
Using cleditor_rails (0.0.3) 
Using coderay (1.0.7) 
Using coffee-script-source (1.3.3) 
Using execjs (1.4.0) 
Using coffee-script (2.2.0) 
Using rack-ssl (1.3.2) 
Using rdoc (3.12) 
Using thor (0.14.6) 
Using railties (3.2.1) 
Using coffee-rails (3.2.2) 
Using columnize (0.3.6) 
Using fssm (0.2.9) 
Using sass (3.1.19) 
Using compass (0.12.2) 
Using compass-rails (1.0.2) 
Using coolline (0.2.0) 
Using diff-lcs (1.1.3) 
Using gherkin (2.11.1) 
Using cucumber (1.2.1) 
Using cucumber-rails (1.3.0) 
Using daemons (1.1.8) 
Using database_cleaner (0.8.0) 
Using debugger-ruby_core_source (1.1.3) 
Using debugger-linecache (1.1.2) 
Using debugger (1.1.4) 
Using delayed_job (3.0.3) 
Using delayed_job_active_record (0.3.2) 
Using orm_adapter (0.3.0) 
Using warden (1.2.1) 
Using devise (2.1.2) 
Using eventmachine (0.12.10) 
Using em-websocket (0.3.6) 
Using rspec-core (2.10.1) 
Using rspec-expectations (2.10.0) 
Using rspec-mocks (2.10.1) 
Using rspec (2.10.0) 
Using email_spec (1.2.1) 
Using factory_girl (3.5.0) 
Using factory_girl_rails (3.5.0) 
Using formtastic (2.2.1) 
Using god (0.12.1) 
Using rb-fchange (0.0.5) 
Using rb-fsevent (0.9.1) 
Using rb-inotify (0.8.8) 
Using listen (0.4.7) 
Using guard (1.1.1) 
Using guard-bundler (1.0.0) 
Using guard-cucumber (1.2.0) 
Using guard-livereload (1.0.0) 
Using guard-migrate (0.1.1) 
Using guard-rails (0.1.0) 
Using guard-rspec (1.1.0) 
Using spork (0.9.2) 
Using guard-spork (1.1.0) 
Using haml (3.1.6) 
Using haml-rails (0.3.4) 
Using hpricot (0.8.6) 
Using jquery-rails (2.0.2) 
Using jquery-ui-rails (1.0.0) 
Using kaminari (0.13.0) 
Using launchy (2.1.0) 
Using linecache19 (0.5.13) from source at ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/linecache19-0.5.13/ 
Using method_source (0.7.1) 
Using mysql2 (0.3.11) 
Using prickle (0.0.6) 
Using slop (2.4.4) 
Using pry (0.9.9.6) 
Using pry-debugger (0.2.0) 
Using yard (0.8.2.1) 
Using pry-doc (0.4.2) 
Using pry-rails (0.1.6) 
Using rack-livereload (0.3.6) 
Using rails (3.2.1) 
Using rails-i18n (0.6.5) 
Using rails3-jquery-autocomplete (1.0.7) 
Using remarkable (4.0.0.alpha4) 
Using remarkable_activemodel (4.0.0.alpha4) 
Using remarkable_activerecord (4.0.0.alpha4) 
Using rspec-rails (2.10.1) 
Using ruby-debug-base19 (0.11.26) from source at ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/ruby-debug-base19-0.11.26/ 
Using ruby-debug19 (0.11.6) 
Using ruby_gntp (0.3.4) 
Using sexp_processor (3.2.0) 
Using ruby_parser (2.3.1) 
Using sass-rails (3.2.5) 
Using shoulda-matchers (1.2.0) 
Using simplecov-html (0.5.3) 
Using simplecov (0.6.4) 
Using syntax (1.0.0) 
Using uglifier (1.2.5) 
Using vpim (0.695) 
Using whenever (0.7.3) 
Using yajl-ruby (1.1.0) 
Your bundle is complete! Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
macbuech:iq josh$ gem list | grep i18n
i18n (0.6.0)
rails-i18n (0.6.5)
macbuech:iq josh$
```

Thanks a lot for clarifications.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You already *were* up to date.

```
macbuech:iq josh$ gem list | grep i18n
i18n (0.6.0)
rails-i18n (0.6.5)
```

You already had version `0.6.5` of `rails-i18n`. It was the other `i18n` gem that you had version `0.6.0` of (and still do)

Comment: **stupid, stupid, stupid! ;-)** It's still early in the morning here... getting another coffee now... Thanks!